# File Input in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, io

I've been searching the internet for a while, but all I can find for file input in C++ is when you know the filename.

I'm trying to write a program to perform an addition of 2 numbers that are greater than 0 from a file, but without using scanf or cin. I want to load the file into memory, but all of the code I can find in regards to this situation requires knowledge of the filename. The file is formatted with 2 integers on a single line, separated by a space, and there are multiple lines of integers. The program will output the sum of the two numbers. I can easily do this with scanf, but if I were given a massive file, I would want to load it into memory (save mapping for later).

Loading the file into memory is giving me trouble, because I do not know the filename, nor how to find out, unless the user inputs the name of the file (not going to happen). I want the program to be executed like so, but using the most raw, and basic forms of C++ IO:

```
./myprog < boatloadofnumbers
```

How would I start my program to take the whole "boatloadofnumbers" as a file, so I can use more basic functions like read()? (also, what is the above method called? passing input?)

```
int main(){
    int a,b;
    while (scanf("%i,%i",&a,&b)>-1){
        printf("%i\n",(a+b));
    } //endwhile
    return 0;
} //endmain
```

Comment: `all I can find for file input in C++ is when you know the filename.` lol. If you are trying to read from a file, and you don't know what the file is called, you are completely SOL. Obviously.

Comment: You are reading from the standard input, not from any file. The shell is redirecting that for you.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see.. Is there another way of reading the data though? I figured I could do some file manipulation if a file were given, but I see that's not the case anymore. I've been trying to work with a more basic method of input than scanf, or to be able to read the data on a larger scale rather than number by number. Do you think you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want to be very GNU, you should allow both reading from the standard input as a default, and from a file if there is an `-f <...>` option on the command line. That's very useful for using your program inside a larger toolchain. Let me know if you want an example.

Comment: @KerrekSB An example would be great.

Comment: Please fix your question title to be different to every other question title ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how you're going to read a file when you don't know the filename. Presumably you don't know the filename at *compile-time*. That's okay, you can get this from the command-line at *runtime*, like this:

```
./myprog boatloadofnumbers
```

Then your filename is in `argv[1]` and you can access it using a `std::ifstream`.

If you're being given the input directly on `stdin` via [**redirection**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) (such as `./myprog < boatloadofnumbers`) you don't need a filename at all, you can just use `std::cin`.

The following `main()` will deal with both of these situations:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Reading from file" << argv[1] << std::endl;
        std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
        if (ifs)
        {
            sum_lines(ifs);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not read from " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Reading from stdin" << std::endl;
        sum_lines(std::cin);
    }
}
```

A sample `sum_lines()` may look a bit like this:

```
void sum_lines(std::istream& is)
{ 
    int first = 0, second = 0;
    std::string line = "";
    while (std::getline(is, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (is >> first >> second)
        {
            std::cout << first << " + " << second << " = " << first + second << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not parse [" << line << "]" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't care from where the input comes, so you can easily inject a `std::istringstream` for unit-testing. Also, this doesn't read the whole file into memory, just one line at a time, so it should deal with `averybigboatloadofnumbers`.

Answer (score 1):

When the program is called as you state, then the content of **boatloadofnumbers** can be read from std::cin.

This method is called *input redirection* and is done by the shell, not your program.

Wiht input redirection the shell usually buffers the content of the file. That's a quite fast way to stream a file a single time through a computation.

Comment: So, how is the input loaded into memory? From what I've been doing, the content is read number by number, the calculation is performed, then it is output. I'd like to read the content on a larger scale than "number by number", because I'm given the content in the form of a file. How do I do that?

Comment: that depends: please show your code, that takes the guessing out of answering.

Comment: Code shown in original post. (all integers are >0... probably should have mentioned that)

Comment: Ok, then please clarify: what is your concern? The program works - is it slower then you expected or what? If that's the case, tell us what you expected performance wise.

Comment: Originally, I was looking for a performance boost. I was unaware of the input redirection, and thought that I was just reading a file, and I could put that file into memory. I was looking for a way to read the input faster than number-by-number in hopes of finding a way to increase its speed.

Comment: @saviourself With ridiculous overengineering you could convert text to binary in one thread, add in one thread, and do formatted output in a third thread.

Comment: your example program would be (disk-)IO limited. There are a lot options: a) accept it, b) read the input from another disk than the output is written to, c) get faster disks, ... make sure you compiled with adequate optimizations

Comment: @ZanLynx How would I get started on something like that? I tried taking in the information as binary, but it didn't like that so much...

Answer (score 0):

With shell redirection, your program can read from the standard input, which may be desirable. However, it may also be desirable to read from a file. It's easy to support both:

```
cat data > ./prog
./prog < data

./prog -f data
```

The first two are similar, and the contents of the file `data` are available from the program's standard input; the third line simply passes a command-line argument. Here's how we support this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

void process_input(std::FILE * fp)
{
    char buf[4];
    std::fread(buf, 4, 1, fp);
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::FILE * fp = stdin; // already open!

    if (argc >= 3 && 0 == std::strcmp(argv[1]. "-f"))
    {
        fp = std::fopen(argv[2], "rb");

        if (!fp)
        {
            std::fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s.\n", argv[2]);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    process_input(fp);

    if (fp != stdin) { std::fclose(fp); }
}
```

Equivalently, you can achieve something similar with iostreams, though it's a bit more roundabout to have a nice, universal reference:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifp;

    if ( /* as before */ )
    {
        ifp.open(argv[2], std::ios::binary);
        if (!ifp) { /* error and die */ }
    }

    std::ifstream & infile = ifp ? ifp : std::cin;

    process_input(infile);
}
```